# TSQL parition in fixed number of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Want to partition result set into groups of n (e.g. 2):

Current result set:

`ColA, ColB
100, A
100, B
100, C
100, D
101, E
101, F
101, G
101, H
101, I`

Have current query that partitions based on unique ColA:

`100, "A,B,C,D"
101, "E,F,G,H,I"`

However, I want to restrict the partitions to no more than 2:

`PartitionId, ColA, ColB
1, 100, A
1, 100, B
2, 100, C
2, 100, D
1, 101, E
1, 101, F
2, 101, G
2, 101, H
3, 101, I`

Then I can partition by the combination of first two columns to generate:

`1, 100, "A,B"
2, 100, "C,D"
1, 101, "E,F"
2, 101, "G,H"
3, 101, "I"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) (plus one, divided by two) and the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
;with cte as (
select *
  , grp = (row_number() over (partition by colA order by colB)+1)/2
from t
)
select 
    grp
  , ColA
  , ColB = stuff((
      select ','+ColB
      from cte i
      where cte.ColA = i.ColA
        and cte.grp = i.grp
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
from cte
group by colA, grp
order by colA, grp
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DUCRPN45791

returns:

```
+-----+------+------+
| grp | ColA | ColB |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 |  100 | A,B  |
|   2 |  100 | C,D  |
|   1 |  101 | E,F  |
|   2 |  101 | G,H  |
|   3 |  101 | I    |
+-----+------+------+
```